# Get the current CMS Status of a channel

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-data-api

I am currently developing a dashboard for a YouTube MCN. I just have a normal Login with youtube for the sign up, that will fetch the normal stats of a channel, ie views, subs, branding etc.

It would be easier if we could grab the CMS Status of the channels linked to the network and save it to the database, and also set up a cron job to our api so we can update these say every 12-24 hours.

I just can't find much information on how to go about this.. anywhere at all really, and I've heard its a common question.

The only scope I am currently using is: **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube**

This is the only data I am currently saving to our database.

```
$_SESSION['youtube']['username']    = $channelsResponse['items'][0]['snippet']['title'];
$_SESSION['youtube']['id']          = $channelsResponse['items'][0]['id'];
$_SESSION['youtube']['description'] = $channelsResponse['items'][0]['snippet']['description'];
$_SESSION['youtube']['thumbnail']   = $channelsResponse['items'][0]['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'];

$_SESSION['youtube']['banner']      = $co['items'][0]['brandingSettings']['image']['bannerImageUrl'];

$_SESSION['youtube']['views']       = $statistics['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount'];
$_SESSION['youtube']['comments']    = $statistics['items'][0]['statistics']['commentCount'];
$_SESSION['youtube']['subscribers'] = $statistics['items'][0]['statistics']['subscriberCount'];
$_SESSION['youtube']['videos']      = $statistics['items'][0]['statistics']['videoCount'];
```

Thank you for your time, and I really appreciate any help I can receive!

Answer (score 0):

If the channel that authenticated is in one of your content owners, you can use the [contentOwnerDetails](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentOwnerDetails) part to retrieve information about the content owner it is in. You have to include the [onBehalfOfContentOwner](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#onBehalfOfContentOwner) parameter to get this information.

If the channel is in another content owner, then there is no way to retrieve this information via the API.